# AsynchTask freezing while a postDelayed handler is running

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I'm pretty new to app development, but I have an issue I can't figure out.

I have a splash screen I am using to load various things that the app needs to function (config files, html from the internet) and the latter is giving me a huge problem. Here is the code

```
Document doc = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        //Fix loading data, dunno why this happens
        try {
            doc = new getHtml().get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity
         * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Utils.saveData(Splash.this, doc);
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, PocketFrameNavigation.class);
                Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                Splash.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }

public static class getHtml extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document> {

        protected Document doInBackground(Void... args) {
            try {
                return Jsoup.connect(DROP_DATA_URL).get();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Document html){
            doc = html;
        }
    }
```

The code that's giving me an issue is the inside the try statement. It seems to freeze the main thread, no matter where I put it. Is there something I am doing terribly wrong? Thanks in advance for the help.

Also, the getHTML function works whenever there is not a post delayed handler involved. so i think it has something to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that will be work:

```
    Document doc = null;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);

            new GetHTMLContent().excute();


        }

        private static class GetHTMLContent extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document> {

            protected Document doInBackground(Void... args) {
                try {
                    return Jsoup.connect(DROP_DATA_URL).get();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Document html){
                doc = html;
                Utils.saveData(Splash.this, doc);
                goToMainActivity();


            }
        }

        private void goToMainActivity(){
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, PocketFrameNavigation.class);
                    Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                    Splash.this.finish();
                }
            }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
        }

}
```